# Filtering model data with Ember Enumerable methods

Tags: ember.js

Full code:

http://jsbin.com/xabome/1/edit?html,js,output

I'm attempting to filter some model data by calling .filter on the record array returned from the store, but it has no effect.

My controller:

```
 App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  fooDataOne: function() {
    var fooData = this.get('fooData');
    // If uncommented, I return both items
    // return fooData;
    return fooData.filter(function(item) {
      console.log("Why am I not filtering?"); // Never called
      if(item.get('id') == 1) { return true; }
    });
  }.property('fooData')
});
```

Is it not possible to call .filter as I'm wanting to here? What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The store.find method always returns a Promise.

So you could filter the data in a then block:

```
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.store.find('test-data').then(function(data) {
      var fooData = data.filter(function(item) {
        return item.get('id') == 1;
      });
      controller.set('fooDataOne', fooData);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found an alternative solution by using an observer and getting a FilteredRecordArray from the store directly:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  fooDataFilter: function() {
    var fooData = this.get('fooData');
    var fooDataOne = this.store.filter('test-data', function(item) {
      if (item.get('id') == 1) { return true; }
    });
    this.set('fooDataOne', fooDataOne);
  }.observes('fooData').on('init')                                                              
});
```

Although the above works, it doesn't explain why the enumerable methods are not working on a a regular DS.RecordArray, which fooData should be.